# Datagridview - proper wat of doing Updating/Inserting

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm doing this for first time and I need some guidance. I have Datagridviews set to It's datasource. Now how do I properly Update or Insert records to DB from It?

My questions:

1. Currently I dont have any buttons under Datagridviews (like Add/Remove/Update - do I need them without doubt or is It possible to handle all actions without them ? - I don't use TableAdapterManager !)
2. MERGE statement - can It be used to compare certain Table with Datagridview and perform Update or Insert on same Table?
3. If doing INSERT or UPDATE manually, what goes first and how to check what must be done ?

I allready have a code for doing both, but It doesn't work as It should, problem is that I have only 1 button for saving data on form - and that button should Insert or Update data in DB from 2 Datagridviews + Databinded Textboxes on form. So basically there are 3 Tables that can be Updated/Inserted on same form - Datagridviews show related data and Databinded Texboxes show master Table record.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT (here is my complete code - first loading data into form and Datagrid, then code for Btn_Save):

```
Imports System.Data
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client ' ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Types

Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form2

    Private da, da1 As OracleDataAdapter
    Private cb, cb1 As OracleCommandBuilder
    Private ds, ds1 As DataSet
    Public OpenedForm1 As Form1 'required for obtaining record ID - this form opens when user double clicks on datagridview record

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            BtnSave.Enabled = False 'for eliminating errors when using dataset Update (Oracle recommendation)
            Dim SQL1 As String = "SELECT * from TABLE1 WHERE ID_Table1=" &  OpenedForm1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
            Dim DGV1_SQL As String = "SELECT ID_TABLE2, ID_TABLE1, Name, Surname, WHERE ID_TABLE1=" & OpenedForm1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
            Dim DGV2_SQL As String = "SELECT TABLE3.SERIAL, TABLE3.MODEL," _
        & " TABLE3.TYPE FROM TABLE3 INNER JOIN (TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE1_TABLE3 ON TABLE1.ID_Table1=TABLE1_TABLE3.ID_Table1_FK) ON " _
        & "TABLE3.ID_Table3=TABLE1_TABLE3.ID_Table3_FK WHERE TABLE1_TABLE3.ID_TABLE1_FKK=" & Openedform1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString

        Try

            Oracleconn()

'Then I do all DB queries and display results on form
'For SQL1 Databind all textboxes – this is a master record on form
'For DGV2_SQL and DGV2_SQL fill datasets and set Datagrids to datasource
'I'm also hiding all primary key fields and bounding datagrids to Binding sources to enable Binding navigators under them.

   End Sub


         Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click

'First I assign some variables for Oracle parameters, such as dealing with Null Date values

           Oracleconn() 'My connection to DB

        Using cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()

            cmd.Connection = Oracleconn()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()

'Adding a lot of paramters here for master record like this...
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("ID", TxtID.Text))
))
'Only Update for master record – Textboxes on form – works just fine
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TABLE1" _
               & " SET ID_TABLE1= : id .etc 

            If Not (TxtSerial.Text = "" Or TxtInventar.Text = "11111" Or TxtInventar.TextLength < 9) Then

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()

'Then checking 1st datagridview for data in It
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV1.Rows

                    If row.Cells(1).Value <> Nothing Then

                        'Adding parameters again

'Then my attempt for doing update or Insert with MERGE – doesn't work

                        cmd.CommandText = "MERGE INTO TABLE2 v" _
                            & "USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID_TABLE2='" & row.Cells(1).Value & "') u" _
                            & " ON u.ID_TABLE2" _
                            & " WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET all fields except ID's " _
                        '    & " WHEN NOT MATCHED BY v" _
                        '    & " THEN INSERT... all fields" _
                        '    & " VALUES.... from parameters"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

                        'This was used before, but ofcourse It only updates 
                        da.Update(ds.Tables(0))

                        BtnSave.Enabled = True

                    Else 
                        MsgBox("You cannot save without 1st field empty !")
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next

'Then check for next Datagrid – this one is hard, It's a joined Table(entitity) from Table1 and Table3, with showing data from that joined Table too
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV2.Rows

'Adding parameters and just performing update – didn't start the Insert so far

                MsgBox("Saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Editing records")

                'Refresh Datagridview in Form1 - which is also opened
                OpenedForm1.BtnSearch()

            Else 
                MsgBox("1st field is required to be filled If you want to save.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Editing records")

            End If

        End Using

        OracleClose() 'close my connection

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us your code - even if it´s not working.

Comment: @Alexb, Ok, I just need some time, will be right back.

Comment: @AlexB., here It is, I had to take some time to change It, my original code is too long for posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to do inserts first, then updates, then deletes.  You must insert parents before children and, unless your foreign keys cascade deletes, delete children before parents.  For updates, it doesn't matter the order.  E.g.

```
Dim parentAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim childAdapter As SqlDataAdapter

Dim data As DataSet

Dim parentTable As DataTable
Dim childTable As DataTable

'...

Dim parentInserts = parentTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)
Dim parentUpdates = parentTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified)
Dim parentDeletes = parentTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted)

Dim childInserts = childTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)
Dim childUpdates = childTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified)
Dim childDeletes = childTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted)

If parentInserts IsNot Nothing Then
    parentAdapter.Update(parentInserts)
End If

If childInserts IsNot Nothing Then
    childAdapter.Update(childInserts)
End If

If parentUpdates IsNot Nothing Then
    parentAdapter.Update(parentUpdates)
End If

If childUpdates IsNot Nothing Then
    childAdapter.Update(childUpdates)
End If

If childDeletes IsNot Nothing Then
    childAdapter.Update(childDeletes)
End If

If parentDeletes IsNot Nothing Then
    parentAdapter.Update(parentDeletes)
End If

data.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: I'm still confused. Do I need buttons for each actions or not ? If not, then how to handle It via code ?....Let's say I have a datagridview with showing records : I change 1st row and write something else in It completely diferrent. In 2nd row I just change some fields. And in 3rd (empty) row I add another new record... How will code know what needs to be deleted, updated, inserted ?

Comment: `DataRowState` is your friend. For updating, you typically don´t need a special button. For adding/deleting there are several options: Context menu, keyboard shortcuts, buttons, ...

Comment: I just showed you what to do.  The code I provided does everything you want.  Have you bothered to study it at all?  What do you think calling `GetChanges` on a `DataTable` does?  Maybe it gets the changes from that `DataTable`.  What do you suppose passing a `DataRowState` of `Added`, `Modified` or `Deleted` does when calling `GetChanges`?  Maybe it limits the changes to just that type.  All you need is to initiate a save and run the code I've provided and everything will be saved.  Obviously you need to change the names to work with your data but the I provided that code for a reason.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I'm learning VB.NET and I'm a beginner, this is my 1st app with DB to create, and It's not an easy design. It will take me a lot of time to practice to get It right, but I'm doing my best with studying a lot. If you take care then look at my edited code, otherwise thank you for your info.

Answer (score 0):

Let Me answer you to the best and honest way as I can because honestly I did that before.

I will answer based on what I used Prog. Lang. and Database and Luckily VB.Net is my Language and MySQL is the database.

My Answers: (Order by your question)

1.Your asking if you need them? For me Yes! because i did that, Think of a form with a `DatagridView` (Populated with Data) and 3 `Buttons` (Add,Update,Delete)

- `Button: Add` will save all your datagridview data in table. You see some link or tutorials [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849212/how-to-insert-each-datagridview-row-into-mysql-db)
- `Button: Edit` will update specific data based on what you selected you can see it [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/211040/display-datagridview-selected-row-in-textboxes). What I did is transfer them to textboxes and do the update.
- `Button: Delete` will delete the data based on your selected row actully the link from button `update` will be your guide you will just edit it and the `Delete Query`

2.10000% YES! see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985535/vb-net-for-each-loop-that-compares-a-row-to-every-other-row) the output of that is to put color in datagridview if both of them are the same. (Sounds exiting? Love it :D)

3.Doing manualy would be hard for me so my tip here is why dont you edit your datagridview then do the `Update Command` Datagridview is editable but Pls provide atleast 1 column that will not be updated because it is the basis of your `where clause`

So there you go I said everything I know and it will depend on you on what you should follow so good luck and happy coding

**Remember :** Theres no wrong in coding One Output Tons of ways to execute

Comment: You don't need multiple buttons.  You add a new row to the grids data source simply by typing into the data entry row at the bottom.  You update and existing row simply by typing into that row.  You delete a row by selecting it and pressing the Delete key.  Once you're done, you save the lot in one go.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for the info sir very appreciated like what I said I gave an answer based on what I did and not what is needed to do. Its only an opinion anyway thanks :)

Comment: @ShadowFiend, thanks for response, but I'm not sure what you meant by 2nd answer, I don't see any relation with MERGE command ?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 do you mean merge two table right? actually you will do it using `datagridview` you will use the Database you used the merging that your pointing will be based on your `Query` example of that is the `INNER JOIN`,`LEFT JOIN` and `OUTER JOIN` or whatever kind of join and the Datagridview will do the display.

Comment: and additional you can make the merge that you want using the Datagridview for example `INNER JOIN Table1,Table2 where Table1.Column = DatagridviewCoulm` you can do that in using the `For Loop` Do the merge you want for every each row in Datagridview.

Comment: @ShadowFiend, no, I meant If merge can be used for single table - to check if there is data to update or just insert. I mentioned that I don't have any buttons for Datagrids. Obviously my serious design flaw, that is why I asked. See my updated code, and you'll see the picture.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 I dont know if i stll understand it but i think your pointing is to check if a certain data exist in the datagridview so you can do the update? and do the insert if data doesnt match am i right? If yes just do the update in existing data then declare a function that will check for new inserted data in dgv and do the insert command there

Comment: @ShadowFiend, did you see my code allready ? I'm using only 1 button to save everything, a lot of checking needs to be done. I'm just asking If I need to separate Update/Insert for each Datagridview or this is just fine. jmcilhinney got me thinked if I need to set just a Datarow.State and then perform either Update or Insert. Would It work ?